# Substituir uma lista por outra lista em um arquivo

Tags: python-3.x

Estou com dificuldades em fazer o passo 4, desejo criar um código pega links em um arquivo e substitui por outros em um HTML já pré formatado com variáveis `@link1@, @link2@...,` porém ele retorna o erro: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

```
#Passo 1 - Lê arquivo com links
arquivo_open = open(path_links, "r")
arquivo = arquivo_open.readlines()

#Passo 2 - Lê HTML
html_open = open(path_html, 'w')

#Passo 3 - Cria os variáveis que serão substituídas
var = ['@links_' + str(i) + '@' for i in range(1,11)]

#Passo 4 - Procura VAR e substitui por ARQUIVO
for url in enumerate(arquivo):
    html.replace(var[0], arquivo[0])
```

Comment: `readlines()` retorna uma lista, isto quer dizer que sua variável `html` é uma lista com as linhas do seu arquivo, o que você quer é substituir os links do arquivo HTML é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quero pegar um arquivo HTML e substituir os links que tem nele por outros links, mas precisam ser correspondentes a ordem da lista

Comment: as linhas são correspondentes: 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, etc?

Comment: sim, linha 1 do arquivo -> @link1@
linha 2 do arquivo ->@link2@